# Materialize Modal Not Opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

The materialize modal is not showing up even after i've followed the steps mentioned in the materialize documentation.
In the console, $(...) modal is not a function error occurs.

I've tried to rearrange the scripts download sequences but none of them seem to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
  rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com
/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize. 
min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->


<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" 
href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn- 
flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>


<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js
/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256- 
DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

</body>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal').modal();
});
</script>

</html>
```

Modal should be displayed but isnt being displayed

Comment: jQuery script tag should be above materialize's script tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo,

> **you need to import jquery before materialize.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal').modal();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
  rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256- 
DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js
/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body>

<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" 
href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn- 
flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```